# NullPointer after execution onPostExecute method

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, gson

I have a problem with retrieving JSON. My JSON looks like this:

```
[{"Kli_nazwa":"miechy ","Kli_adres":"miechowity ","Kli_nip":"12"},{"Kli_nazwa":"mi? ","Kli_adres":"szp 39","Kli_nip":"19"}]
```

The app is throwing a NullPointerException in onPostExecute, even if thr JSON was retrieved correctly. What it's going on? I am totally stuck.

```
private class PHPConnection_Klient extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        wynik_klienci = getResponseKli();

        return wynik_klienci;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String wynik_klienci) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(wynik_klienci);
        System.out.println(wynik_klienci);

        Gson g1 = new Gson();

        List<Klient> klient = Arrays.asList(g1.fromJson(wynik_klienci,
                Klient[].class));

        try {
            klientDao.delete(klientDao.queryForAll());

            if (klient != null) {
                for (Klient k : klient) {
                    klientDao.create(k);
                }
            }

        } catch (final SQLException e) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
}

private String getResponseKli() {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpGet request1 = new HttpGet(
            "myURL");

    try {
        HttpResponse response1 = client.execute(request1);

        String w1 = EntityUtils.toString(response1.getEntity());

        return w1;
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "";
}
```

Errors:

```
03-19 10:29:06.395: W/dalvikvm(5851): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught  exception (group=0x40be01f8)
03-19 10:29:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(5851): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-19 10:29:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(5851): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-19 10:29:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(5851):     at  com.android.internal.os.LoggingPrintStream.println(LoggingPrintStream.java:298)
03-19 10:29:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(5851):     at com.example.inzynierka.MainActivity$PHPConnection_Klient.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:627)
03-19 10:29:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(5851):     at com.example.inzynierka.MainActivity$PHPConnection_Klient.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
03-19 10:29:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(5851):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
03-19 10:29:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(5851):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
03-19 10:29:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(5851):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
03-19 10:29:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(5851):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-19 10:29:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(5851):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-19 10:29:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(5851):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
03-19 10:29:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(5851):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 10:29:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(5851):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-19 10:29:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(5851):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
03-19 10:29:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(5851):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
03-19 10:29:06.403: E/AndroidRuntime(5851):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And this is how i'm executing two PHPConnections:

```
PHPConnection_Klient php_kli = new PHPConnection_Klient();
        php_kli.execute();
        PHPConnection_Kategoria php_kt = new PHPConnection_Kategoria();

        php_kt.execute();
```

Comment: Can you show the stack trace?

Comment: your background method is string type and your are returning null.that why you are getting null.change it to return wynik_klienci in background method.

Comment: @DavidWallace take a look on it

Comment: @Pankaj i've changed it and there is no progress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are returining null and you should `return wynik_klienci`

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    wynik_klienci = getResponseKli();
    return wynik_klienci;
}
```

since you are hiding the scope of the class member `wynik_klienci`, calling the formal parameter of `onPostExecute` the same way of it

Comment: Sir @blackelt there is still error, even after changes you adviced to make

Comment: no it is not possible. Run it again and check carefully for the error

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in Android, oddly, `System.out.println` will throw this exception if you pass it a null, and that's what's happening here.  So I guess you should put some logic into `onPostExecute` so that if a null is passed in, it just exits gracefully, or does whatever else you require it to do.

Comment: Walance, but it shouldn't be empty. It should write json format. I just want to see that json was correctly downloaded.